# ajax jquery always running Error

Tags: jquery

Everytime I run my ajax jquery function I get an error, this goes for all my ajax calls.
here is an example of my code

```
 function FindContact(CompanyName,DivisionName,FirstName,LastName) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Path',
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            type:'post',
            data: {'FirstName':FirstName,'LastName':LastName,'DivisionName':DivisionName,'CompanyName':CompanyName},
            success: DisplayContacts,
            error: ErrorMsg
        });
    }
```

to get around this I use this

```
 function ErrorMsg(result) {
        if (result.status == 200 && result.statusText == 'OK') {
            DisplayContacts(result);
        }
        else {
            alert("FAILED : " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }
    }
```

this is tough because I need to create method like this for every ajax request.

why does it run the error code 1st???

Please help!

Comment: Ensure that what you are returning is valid json. If its not, and everything goes correct on the server, $.ajax will go to error rather than success.

Comment: Hello,
- Have you checked what the status code is (using .alert())?
- Have you checked that the target page uses the same method to send the results back?

Comment: @locrizak: how to I check that I am returning a valid json

Comment: Quick way is to just switch dataType to html and see the success is being fired. Another way to check if valid json is being returned is, open up firebug and when the request gets sent, click on the response tab, copy the response and got to http://www.jsonlint.com/ to check if its valid.

Comment: @locrizak: please post that as the answer also provide a links with different dataTypes :)

Comment: I found out that if you DID echo in the PHP, it might messed up the JSON string therefore it will call the error part in the JQUERY. What I did was eliminate all the echo, only remain the json_encode($string).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Ensure that what you are returning is valid json. If its not, and everything goes correct on the server, $.ajax will go to error rather than success.

```
 function FindContact(CompanyName,DivisionName,FirstName,LastName) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Path',
            dataType: "html or json",
            async:false,
            type:'post',
            data: {'FirstName':FirstName,'LastName':LastName,'DivisionName':DivisionName,'CompanyName':CompanyName},
            success: DisplayContacts,
            error: ErrorMsg
        });
    }
```

A quick to check if the json is valid is to just switch dataType to html and see the success is being fired. If it is than your json is invalid, if your still getting the same problem thers something else wrong.

Another way to check if valid json is being returned is, open up firebug and when the request gets sent, click on the response tab, copy the response and got to jsonlint.com to check if its valid.

[Jquery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: you saved my day, Thanks :) dataType: json is what i was looking at :)

Answer (score 3):

My solution was a difference in Accept-Type and Content-Type headers. If the client-side request's Accept-Type header does not match the server-side response's Content-Type header, Jquery will call the error callback.

Jquery, by default, sets the Accept-Type header to `application/json`. However, my server was sending a response with Content-Type `application/x-javascript`.  My fix was to change the server-side response Content-Type header to the appropriate `application/json`.

Comment: how did you change the content type header on the server side? +1 if you answer me.

Comment: What server-side environment do you have? I'm on php so mine was:

    `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue when making an ajax call using jquery ajax. I fixed it using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/url",
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(result){ alert(result); },
  error: ErrorMsg,
});
```

Note: **dataType: 'text'** parameter, it worked for me.